# Purpose of this diode

Tags: diodes, schematics

I am trying to understand [this](https://ez.analog.com/cfs-file/__key/telligent-evolution-components-attachments/00-383-00-00-00-01-67-51/CDIAN003_2D00_GaN_2D00_Bias_2D00_Bd.pdf) circuit.

There is a diode D2 connected parallel to MOSFET M1 on page 9.

[image]

I got the idea that it might be used for protecting the MOSFET.

Can someone explain to me the exact use of this diode?

[image]

Comment: The complete circuit is needed as well as the type of device it is used in. Show all power rails and components that connect to the gate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [data sheet documentation for the LT4256](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/425612fa.pm6.pdf), it also uses an IRF530 but, in that circuit, it relies on the internal bulk diode for any necessary reverse protection: -

[image]

I expect that the person designing this circuit may have been unsure about the presence of the internal MOSFET bulk diode and may just have played safe and included an extra one.

The internal bulk diode is rated for 14 amps continuous current and has the same current rating as the MOSFET itself.

Answer (score 2):

It may be a Zener TVS for protecting the transistor from overvoltage spikes.

Answer (score 0):

99.9% of n and p MOSFET's have a diode in parallel in order to protect the channel from reverse polarity.

When you buy a MOSFET you buy its diode.

In your case, the diode is useful to discharge all capacitors present on the VDD rail at power-off.

That diode by-passes and protects MOSFET M1 when VDD_1 goes to zero voltage.

Comment: The IRF530 has an internal bulk diode that serves that purpose.

Comment: All Mosfet's do.

Comment: There's a distinct dearth of information here, but based on the rather low voltage rating I would assume it is a Schottky diode with a much lower Vf than the bulk diode so it would tend to take most of the current when forward biased.